# Scroll between tags in Awesome WM

Tags: window-manager, composite, scrolling, awesome

How can I add smooth scrolling between tags in the Awesome WM? I realize I can't run compiz with Awesome. Is there something comparable that I can run? I don't need any other effects, switching between tags quickly is just disoreinting when it jumps as it does.

EDIT: While I didn't find an exact answer, cairo-compmgr gives smooth fading between tags and clients. I'm satisfied :)

Answer (score 5):

Tags in `awesome` are not monolithic slates or work-spaces that could be "scrolled to". In general you have to re-think what you are looking at. **Tags are not separately rendered spaces, they are lists of windows.** This is part of the flexibility of awesome and allows you to do things other window managers cannot, such as pull up more than one tag at once - rendering them in whatever layout the first called tag is defined with.

The  other tags besides the one you are looking at are not being rendered in another space, they are not being shown by X at all. When a different tag is called the current windows are hidden and the other tagged windows drawn.

You can see the effects of this if you have a poorly programmed application that re-renders itself on being re-shown even if it the same size. These apps will take a noticeable amount of time to pull up when you switch tag views.

While it might be technically possible to re-write everything with OpenGL or some other buffered system so you could pre-render things before showing them and thus show transition effects, this isn't the focus of the `awesome` project and I don't expect to see a feature like that soon. **Enjoy it for what it is.**

Comment: Whether you think of workspaces as sets of tags or separate bins in which to place windows is unrelated to whether there is some visual effect when you change the set of displayed windows. It's true that the kind of people who like highly configurable window managers such as awesome also rarely want special effects and so are less likely to write code for them, but it's a culture clash, not a technical clash.